# How to wait for user to press enter key in J-Query Text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, html-lists, backend

I want to add validation on my text field that is, after filling the text field user will press enter key and that text should be added to the list, and if the text field is empty or the user presses the wrong key it will show and error in any form.
But during typing is starts showing an error not waiting for the user to press enter key.

```js
$(function(){
    $("#enterBtn").click(handleBindingsOnClick);
    $("#input").keyup(handleBindingsOnPress);
});
function handleBindings(){
    var newtodo = $("#input").val();
    $("#todos").append("<li>"+ newtodo +"</li>");
    $("#input").val("");
}
function handleBindingsOnClick(){
    if($("#input").val() != ""){
        handleBindings();
    }
}
function handleBindingsOnPress(event){
    if(event.keyCode === 13 && $("#input").val() != ""){
        handleBindings();
    }
    else{
        alert("Please press enter key or fill the field");
    }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your Text" />
<button id="enterBtn">Enter</button>
<ul id="todos">
   <li>Cricket</li>
   <li>CC</li>
   <li>Web</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write **else if** see below code

```
function handleBindingsOnPress(event){
  if(event.keyCode === 13 && $("#input").val() != ""){
      handleBindings();
  }
  else if(event.keyCode === 13 && $("#input").val() === ""){
      alert("Please press enter key or fill the field");
  }
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/sq4L1t67/

```js
$(function(){
$("#enterBtn").click(handleBindingsOnClick);
$("#input").keyup(handleBindingsOnPress);
});
function handleBindings(){
var newtodo = $("#input").val();
$("#todos").append("<li>"+ newtodo +"</li>");
$("#input").val("");
}
function handleBindingsOnClick(){
if($("#input").val() != ""){
    handleBindings();
}
}
function handleBindingsOnPress(event){
  if(event.keyCode === 13 && $("#input").val() != ""){
      handleBindings();
  }
  else if(event.keyCode === 13 && $("#input").val() === ""){
      alert("Please press enter key or fill the field");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your Text" />
<button id="enterBtn">Enter</button>
<ul id="todos">
  <li>Cricket</li>
  <li>CC</li>
  <li>Web</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `setTimeout` and use that to wait `X` seconds to see when the user is finished typing.

```
var typingTimer;
var doneTypingInterval = 2000;

function handleBindingsOnPress(event) {
  clearTimeout(typingTimer);
  if (event.keyCode === 13 && $("#input").val() != "") {
    handleBindings();
  } else {
    typingTimer = setTimeout(function() {
      alert("Please press enter key or fill the field");
    }, doneTypingInterval);
  }
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var typingTimer; //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 2000; //time in ms (5 seconds)

$(function() {
  $("#enterBtn").click(handleBindingsOnClick);
  $("#input").keyup(handleBindingsOnPress);
});

function handleBindings() {
  var newtodo = $("#input").val();
  $("#todos").append("<li>" + newtodo + "</li>");
  $("#input").val("");
}

function handleBindingsOnClick() {
  if ($("#input").val() != "") {
    handleBindings();
  }
}

function handleBindingsOnPress(event) {
  clearTimeout(typingTimer);
  if (event.keyCode === 13 && $("#input").val() != "") {
    handleBindings();
  } else {
    typingTimer = setTimeout(function() {
      alert("Please press enter key or fill the field");
    }, doneTypingInterval);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your Text" />
<button id="enterBtn">Enter</button>
<ul id="todos">
  <li>Cricket</li>
  <li>CC</li>
  <li>Web</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the JS `keydown` event for this. Check the below code for the desired result.

```js
$(function(){
    $("#enterBtn").click(handleBindingsOnClick);
    $('#input').on('keydown', function(e) {
      if (e.which == 13) {
          handleBindingsOnClick();
      }
  });
});
function handleBindings(){
    var newtodo = $("#input").val();
    $("#todos").append("<li>"+ newtodo +"</li>");
    $("#input").val("");
}
function handleBindingsOnClick(event){
    if($("#input").val() != ""){
        handleBindings();
    } else {
        alert("Please press enter key or fill the field");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your Text" />
<button id="enterBtn">Enter</button>
<ul id="todos">
   <li>Cricket</li>
   <li>CC</li>
   <li>Web</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome, @JawadAli, You can upvote and accept this answer so that it can help anyone else.